# PDF attachment appears as random text in the body

Tags: email, pdf

I'm a developer with little knowledge of email ...stuff. I've been tasked with solving a problem related to that email stuff.

We have a problem with certain pdf email reports being sent to us (they are generated by a third-party software, but from what I can tell, that software is using our own MX servers to send it to us). I have copied header info below, but after some simple tests:

1) WORKS - Gmail/hotmail recipient - PDF appears correctly as an attachment

2) DOES NOT WORK - OURDOMAIN.com recipient OR Rogers.com recipient (both online and MS outlook client) - PDF appears as gibberish (I know, its not really gibberish):

```
begin 666 /data/[file path and name here].pdf
M)5!$1BTQ+C0-"B7Y^IKG#0HT(#`@;V)J#0H\/`HO12`T.#`P.`HO2"!;-#(X...
```

3) WORKS - Forward Gmail/hotmail email to OURDOMAIN

4) WORKS - Forward the gibberish email from test 2 to gmail or hotmail

If anyone has experienced this issue, any advice on how to resolve this issue (either through telling the third party to change their email script, or adjust our mail server settings)?

Headers:

Internet headers from outlook (File > Properties):

```
Received: from qad1.OURDOMAIN.com (10.99.41.10) by
 SCOOTEX01A.AD.OURDOMAIN.com (10.99.42.100) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
 14.3.210.2; Thu, 10 Jan 2019 10:57:26 -0500
Received: (from root@localhost) by qad1.OURDOMAIN.com (8.9.3
 (PHNE_35950)/8.9.3) id KAA16277;   Thu, 10 Jan 2019 10:56:46 -0500 (EST)
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2019 10:56:46 -0500
From: <root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com>
Message-ID: <201901101556.KAA16277@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com>
To: <me@gmail.com>, <others@OURDOMAIN.com>,
    <me@OURDOMAIN.com>
Subject: TYGMSPOSD DELJIT Report
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Return-Path: root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SCOOTEX01a.AD.OURDOMAIN.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 10
```

GMAIL:

```
Delivered-To: me@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a50:95ed:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id x42csp2161688eda;
        Thu, 10 Jan 2019 08:27:56 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ALg8bN5RiZ6QpXjU5ifJAaYoJwUkq5VUHg8XQOv9eEWgSVx8vPBM8u71ToT4dGz6/jMMn8Jc2YuL
X-Received: by 2002:a5e:db44:: with SMTP id r4mr6416635iop.142.1547137675743;
        Thu, 10 Jan 2019 08:27:55 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1547137675; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=TQgJBOipnrDgMmj7fDV9akUi4gxHPIaUaqGPQqOToSzjvqMZvh/IzAjs3WHSQ1diVD
         OBYBMniGUR8PohtuJ5dJPCJUrW+E3eNEu8KoVXyc1F0WNWqPmnWAi4zT4eY76cBnMgX6
         ejOsFwJwxERcAmj65riCQ0hwMWiq8zyg6XJiohDBIMWc5cIvrR4AWfw3odzg5RYc4Kdo
         Sop8+IRjlqzAAhAtpLcZVZ14U1Of4EpsTEUhDkb7DL9oAZqsUIe8pO5ZBep4UG4GzWc6
         rLGdDMk7iVZKF03F7E05IX5zo1GBu9QKfC9sRfKIehHxiuubiVWhU2OWiDu7CqvgIsdV
         31Uw==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:subject:to:message-id:from
         :date;
        bh=XnZ3szAGfipXM3+HnWo9CKZKYWY1Uud5fCUWvPMPKEU=;
        b=jwbok8bSBv12Rn4k/SisV0FFxBP2uxvtAiejIuhuhlUTcUhL3Uh6l4xRIL5CaiMrKV
         jkRxiDVk7pimXjjayPGdUCFbKqrkgQbxXMi/x9iwSnPluDLyqErLf38OYg0B4E/MBxOn
         evNlHIfLZa90lWo89emwtle2uKwr2lPpASjMva5TiQtmWzkcm/OZQYhgEDayJC2EhwxM
         uxZ7S2NqiUMfJ6R/KkhZUq+EOwHW9zieDoZ0jYTBWFAVGnhUVmdA+yW4LFlmHnfQYpOj
         xtII441ow1VrwKUYaUVYi3jainGd+VzSIVdp9tC2XVX3J5RN1dbi/y4x+OHie3XG4Gcj
         01eg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com designates 209.171.90.3 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com
Return-Path: <root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com>
Received: from mail3.OURDOMAIN.com (mail3.OURDOMAIN.com. [209.171.90.3])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id r15si10247731itc.55.2019.01.10.08.27.55
        for <me@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 10 Jan 2019 08:27:55 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com designates 209.171.90.3 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.171.90.3;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com designates 209.171.90.3 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com
X-ASG-Debug-ID: 1547137671-09c42418c2374140002-QUTJxp
Received: from SCOOTEX01a.AD.OURDOMAIN.com ([10.99.42.100]) by mail3.OURDOMAIN.com with ESMTP id pVkVkwY1yxfRxEA7; Thu, 10 Jan 2019 11:27:53 -0500 (EST)
X-Barracuda-Envelope-From: root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com
X-ASG-Whitelist: Sender
Received: from qad1.OURDOMAIN.com (10.99.41.10) by SCOOTEX01A.AD.OURDOMAIN.com (10.99.42.100) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 14.3.210.2; Thu, 10 Jan 2019 11:06:51 -0500
Received: (from root@localhost) by qad1.OURDOMAIN.com (8.9.3 (PHNE_35950)/8.9.3) id LAA24693;   Thu, 10 Jan 2019 11:06:12 -0500 (EST)
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2019 11:06:12 -0500
From: <root@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com>
Message-ID: <201901101606.LAA24693@qad1.OURDOMAIN.com>
To: <me@gmail.com>, <others@OURDOMAIN.com>, <me@OURDOMAIN.com>
Subject: TYGMSPOSD DELJIT Report
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-ASG-Orig-Subj: TYGMSPOSD DELJIT Report
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Barracuda-Connect: UNKNOWN[10.99.42.100]
X-Barracuda-Start-Time: 1547137672
X-Barracuda-URL: https://10.99.42.22:443/cgi-mod/mark.cgi
X-Virus-Scanned: by bsmtpd at OURDOMAIN.com
X-Barracuda-Scan-Msg-Size: 67734
X-Barracuda-BRTS-Status: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the headers that you posted, it looks like the application that is creating and sending these email messages is using [UUENCODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) to attach the PDF to the message.  UUENCODE is a very old encoding method for attaching files to emails, which pre-dates MIME encoding which is much more common these days.

While it seems from what you are saying that Gmail and Hotmail still support UUENCODE, it seems that Outlook (and possibly Microsoft Exchange) does not.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2590107/inline-uuencoded-attachments-of-email-messages-from-a-unix-based-appli

If the application that is creating and sending these emails can be updated to use MIME encoding instead of UUENCODE, that should solve the problem.